# How does defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access') work?

Tags: security, joomla

This line is on the top of templates and modules:

`defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');`

And from the [Joomla! Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Why_do_most_of_the_Joomla!_PHP_files_start_with_%22defined%28%27_JEXEC%27%29...?):

> This statement checks to see if the file is being called from within a Joomla! session and it protects your site by making it more difficult for a cracker/hacker to damage your site.

`_JEXEC` is defined in the `index.php` file in the root directory of the Joomla! site [[source]](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/create-template/defined-jexec-or-die), what stops someone from defining `_JEXEC` in their own site and including my module, since `defined('_JEXEC')` would return true then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess if a hacker has control of your site the _JEXEC - test will not have any function. But as long as someone is just trying to break your site, the code will make sure they can not execute files directly in the file-hierachy, but always have to enter through /index.php.

> what stops someone from defining _JEXEC in their own site and
>   including my module

This is not possible. If you try to include a php-file on another site, all that will be returned to you is the generated output, not the php-code itself, right?

regards Jonas

Comment: But this line would be useless in a file that only contains declarations, like classes and functions?

Comment: Yes, nothing will be executed by calling such a file, and any compile time error will be thrown regardless of the _JEXEC - statement.

Comment: Good to know, since PSR-2 standard collides with having both side-effects and class declarations in the same file (not that Joomla supports namespaces, another requirement for PSR-2...). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to keep Joomla executing in the right order. Your code could throw errors without the preceding actions that could give information to attackers.